# Minecraft minecart quirks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I read recently that redstone circuits have a [North-South quirk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#The_North.2FSouth_Quirk), where circuit delays are different depending on whether a redstone torch faces North/South or East/West.

Do minecarts have any directional related quirks?

Comment: Any reason why people want to close this question? The lack of comments doesn't help me :(

Comment: Current close reason is Not A Real Question: *"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."* Note that you can click on the "close" to see what the current reasons are, in case you were not yet aware. As far as this question goes, I guess people think it might qualify under the overly broad or vague, perhaps because your original title was unclear and the minecart stuff is buried at the end.

Comment: @Grace thanks, I didn't click close earlier because I thought it might instantly close the question.

Comment: Hah, an understandable concern. When you can vote to close on your own questions, it only counts as one vote and you still have to specify which kind of vote. You can't unilaterally close your own question.

Comment: **Note**: It's no longer possible to create boosters. Although the intersection rule still applies...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minecarts will favour travelling south or west (known as the South-West rule) when they reach an intersection. Also, placed tracks will favour curving south or west. Additionally, when two minecarts are adjacent to each other, they will speed up extremely quickly,. This is commonly called a [booster](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Booster). The South-West rule is used when making self-resetting boosters:

[image: Image courtesy of the Minecraft Wiki]

Comment: Neat! Is this an exhaustive list of minecart quirks or should I be reading about them more?

Comment: These are the two big quirks when it comes to minecarts (other than boosters which you're probably already aware of). I'll edit information about boosters in anyways.

Comment: The more information the better. Screen caps are good too :)

Comment: You could add arrows on the booster track, showing that the minecart resets because it favours going down (booster at the left side of pic) or left (booster at the top of pic).

Comment: **Note**: It's no longer possible to create boosters. Although the intersection rule still applies...